# Writing RSA Private Key to PEM File with Passphrase

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa

I am writing a C++ function to create an RSA key pair and store the private key in a PEM file. I use code as in the following example:

```
static unsigned char passphrase[] = "0123456789";
int keySize = 2048;
int keyExponent = 65537;
BIGNUM *bn;
. . .
bn = BN_new();
BN_set_word(bn, keyExponent);
rsa = RSA_new();
RSA_generate_key_ex(rsa, keySize, bn, nullptr);
FILE* fp = fopen(fileName, "w");
PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(fp, rsa, EVP_des_ede3_cbc(), passphrase, 10, nullptr, nullptr);
```

This code works as expected but now I have been asked to store the private key without passphrase protection. Is there a way to get function `PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey` not to use a passphrase? One option I tried is to change the function call as follows:

```
outcome = PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(fp, rsa, EVP_des_ede3_cbc(), nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
```

But this results in a prompt to the user to enter a passphrase (which is exactly as stated in the documentation of function PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey). I also tried using a passphrase call-back which returns zero (to signify that there is no passphrase) but this results in `PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey` returning an error.

What else can I do to have a private key stored in a PEM file without passphrase? I assume that this must somehow be possible because I can do it using openssl commands such as: `openssl genrsa -out tmsPrivKey.pem 2048`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter is the encryption cipher to use to encrypt the private key with. So all you need to do is pass a nullptr to the function.

e.g.

```
outcome = PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(fp, rsa, nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
```

From the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey.html):

> The PEM functions which write private keys take an enc parameter which
>   specifies the encryption algorithm to use, encryption is done at the
>   PEM level. If this parameter is set to NULL then the private key is
>   written in unencrypted form.

Comment: Thanks! I now see that I had misunderstood the meaning of the third parameter in function PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey.